# HI, I am new and don't really know what I am doing could someone help me with my project

Tags: python

**This is what it gives me when I run it.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    name2 = int(input("What whould you like me to call you",  name1))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

**This is my work**

```
#Birthday
feeling = input("Hello, how are you doing? ")
print("Good to hear you're doing well")
name1 = input("And what is your name: "  )
print("Lovely name ;) ")
name2 = int(input("What would you like me to call you",  name1))
print("Welcome to Birthday Plaza where we do all the work for you", name2)
```

Comment: why did you int name2??

Comment: Read the documentation: `input` takes only one argument.  You have to concatenate the string you want for the prompt.  Separating the pieces with commas doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do what you want is like this:

```
text = "What would you like me to call you, " + name1 + "?\n"
name2 = input(text)
```

`input` does not work like `print`. It can take only one argument. You can prepare your question and save it in a variable and then call `input` with it.

Comment: Thank you soo much you help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**input expected at most 1 argument, got 2**

Also, don't cast to int.

This should work:

```
name2 = input("What would you like me to call you")
```

Comment: Thank you soo much you help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
a = "What would you like me to call you"
a += name1
name2 = input(a)
```

OR

```
name2 = input("What would you like me to call you " + name1)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much you help a lot.